# Blank display in sonarqube issue list

Tags: sonarqube

I just installed the current version of sonar qube (6.5 at the moment, from 6.2) and have a strange issue with the display of the issues list in the web frontend.

For some projects (not depending on the number of issues) the issue list empty (or better blank, as all issues are counted and the category pane looks fine, but the issues are not shown).
[image: issue list blank]

Pressing right arrow key jumps to a different view, where on the left all issues in the list are displayed, but on the right hand side, again there is just a blank pane where in other projects the source file is displayed to navigate.
[image: source pane blank]

I tested with Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Additional information from the debug feature (F12)

There is this error on the issue list pane

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

in `app.bf342fee.js:1:73074`

There is an error message on the source file pane with trace (there is also a trace for the issue list pane, but it is too long to post it here too)

```
TypeError: n is null
Stack-Trace:
mountComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:824978
mountComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123351
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812460
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
  vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:2113
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: n is null
Stack-Trace:
mountComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:824978
mountComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123351
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812460
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843045
_updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843791
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:843689
_updateDOMChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:830598
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828804
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:828357
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
_updateRenderedComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819282
_performComponentUpdate@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:819036
updateComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:818314
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:817431
receiveComponent@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:123745
updateChildren@http://build:9000/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js:1:812341
```

Comment: Are you sure you have Browse permissions on these projects?

Comment: Do you see any error messages using the F12 tools?

Comment: @G. Ann - Where do I find those. In "Permissions" I can see only "Administer Issues", "Administer", and "Execute Analysis"

Answer (score 1):

The first question to ask in this situation is whether you have Browse permission on the project. Without Browse, you could see that issues exist, but not be able to see them in the file context which is pretty much your symptom except that there ought to be a notification in the UI in that case.

However, since the project permissions don't give you Browse as an option to toggle, this means that your project is Public, and everyone has Browse by default.

So you probably have a corrupted Elasticsearch index.

- stop the server
- delete $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es
- restart the server (time here varies by instance size)

Comment: Hi, I removed the Elasticsearch index, but this does not change anything. Still the blank pages.

Comment: OK, after waiting a week, now everything seems fine. Don't know why. Maybe a new analysis was needed after removing the es index.

Comment: I have the same issue again after upgrade to 7.1. Deleting the el index does not seem to do anything.